# ios8 Timezone parsing changed?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Has the parsing for timzones changed in iOS8?

I try to parse the date "2014-09-03 12:20:38.000 +0200"

with this code and get nil:

```
-(NSDateFormatter*) dateAndTimeFormatter{
    if(!_dateAndTimeFormatter){
        _dateAndTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [_dateAndTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZZZ"];
        _dateAndTimeFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        _dateAndTimeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    }
    return _dateAndTimeFormatter;
}
```

alternatively

```
[_dateAndTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"];
```

doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `dateStyle` or `timeStyle` will override any custom `dateFormat` you have set. Your date string does not conform in any way to `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`, which is why you are getting nil when trying to convert strings to dates.

Furthermore, according to [Unicode Technical Standard #35 revision 31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), the timezone specifier of "ZZZZZ" corresponds to date strings with formats like "-08:00" or "-07:52:58", not "+0200" as you have in your example. One of the specifiers that matches "+0200" is the one with one to three capital "Z" characters.

This should work for you:

```
- (NSDateFormatter *)dateAndTimeFormatter {
    if (!_dateAndTimeFormatter) {
        _dateAndTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [_dateAndTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ"];
    }
    return _dateAndTimeFormatter;
}
```

Also, note that your code should also not be working prior to iOS 8.

Comment: This is bang on.  Funny how the OP implies that code used to work before iOS 8, which doesn't help matters.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would try is to reset your time settings in XCode: settings -> general -> date time -> time format (either set to 24 hour or reset the selection).

If that does not work, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) is a guide to overwrite the locale which is basically:
`formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];`

Comment: I don't have this setting in XCode 6

Comment: Setting the locale didn't helped too. But if I po self.dateAndTimeFormatter.dateFormat I get dd.MM.yy HH:mm